# Android seekbar - no color tint parameters

Tags: android, xamarin, seekbar, android-sdk-manager

See what's installed in the picture

[image]

Emulator is set to 4.4.2. MinSDK set to 16.

Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:progressBackgroundTint' etc

Seekbar does not have the following parameters: colorControlActivated, progressbackgroundtint, progresstint, thumbtint

How to change color of seekbar?

**Main.axml** seekbar style:

```
<SeekBar
    p1:layout_width="250dp"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ... />
```

**Xamarin.Diagnostics**

```
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (path hidden by user\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (path hidden by user\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r11c\).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Novell\Mono for Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (path hidden by user\Java\jdk1.8.0_151).
[I:Unknown]:              Found Xamarin.Android 7.0.2
[I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 17, 19
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'path hidden by user\\.android\avd'
[D:]:                     avd watcher android path: 'path hidden by user\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\android.BAT'
[W:]:                     Adb connection refused
[I:]:                     Starting Adb server (adb start-server)
[I:]:                     Adb start-server operation completed
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 1 devices
```

Comment: Is xamarin required in your question?

Comment: You have a xamarin tag! Is an alternative way of making android apps, there are many ways of making android apps, do you want an answer that uses xamarin only?

Comment: You have a xamarin tag! Is an alternative way of making android apps, there are many ways of making android apps, do you want an answer that uses xamarin only?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

> How to change color of seekbar?

Android `SeekBar` custom material style, you could refer to :

http://www.zoftino.com/android-seekbar-and-custom-seekbar-examples

Create your custom `SeekBar` style :

```
<style name="MySeekBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">#f4511e</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">#388e3c</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#c51162</item>
</style>
```

Use it in your `axml` :

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/mySeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MySeekBar"
    />
```

Effect :

[image]

## Update :

Please  make sure you have add the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` in your `axml`, if you have add this in your `axml`, please post your complete `axml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/mySeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/MySeekBar"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @SWA, how did you use these parameters in your `SeekBar` ? Please post your code.

Comment: @SWA, try replace `p1:` with `android:`.

Comment: @SWA, that's wierd, could you please share a basic demo to reproduce this problem ?

Comment: @SWA, it's possible, could you please share a [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output)? That would be really appreciated!

Comment: @SWA, you mean project solution ?

Comment: Go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solution -> Build and Run -> MSBuild ... -> Select Diagnostic.